# Bundle returning Null when called in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, bundle, android-adapter

I am trying to pass string from Adapter to fragment in Bundle bu ti'm getting null in my Fragment

Here is my code to add string to Bundle

```
            Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("id",expense_id);
            AddExpenseFragment fragment=new AddExpenseFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            UiActivity.startAddExpense(context);
```

this is my code to retrieve to Bundle value in Fragment

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment_add_expense,container,false);
    String id=this.getArguments().getString("id");
    return view;
}
```

and i'm passing bundle value from My recyclerView Adapter class

Comment: What is you `startAddExpense` method doing ?

Comment: @David it's calling intent to start the fragment activity

Comment: Would you please show me the line where you commit your fragment with fragment transaction ? I assume you are starting not the fragment for which you pass the arguments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is simple here. You are creating a fragment and setting data to it which is fine,

```
AddExpenseFragment fragment=new AddExpenseFragment();
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

But the problem is in your

```
UiActivity.startAddExpense(context);
```

**you must be replacing with a new instance** of the `AddExpenseFragment` as you are no where passing the newly created fragment instance (with the arguments set to it) to the `startAddExpense()` method.

The solution is simple, just pass the newly created fragment object to the startAddExpense() like this,

```
UiActivity.startAddExpense(context, fragment);
```

and then inside the method replace or add this new fragment and **do not instantiate any new fragment object**.

Comment: okay that might be the problem how do I bind fragment while starting the activity

thanks

Comment: Glad it helped you. It is a completely separate question and not related to this. It is better to ask a separate question for that. If you problem is solved, please accept the answer. It helps maintain the community standards.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
String id=bundle.getString("id");
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it's hard to find problems.just give your some suggestions.
Firstly, check whether your variable expense_id is null or not.
Secondly, check whether the AddExpenseFragment you created and really showed are the same.